# How to subtract two unsigned numpy arrays to give a signed result?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to subtract two unsigned numpy arrays and get a signed result. I don't know the types in advance. Casting both to int64 works, but this needlessly wastes space if the inputs are uint8 (casting to int16 would suffice).

I have thought of writing a function that returns the next larger signed type (e.g. uint8->int16), maxing out at the largest signed type. However, I'm not sure how to do that without hard-coding a table of data types, which could go out of date.

I thought numpy.results_type or numpy.promote_type might help, but I could not figure out how to use them for this purpose.

Does anyone have a clean solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `newtype = np.promote_types(x.dtype, np.byte)`, where `x` is your unsigned array with unknown dtype. Since `np.byte` is the smallest possible signed integer type, `newtype` will be the smallest signed integer type to which `x` can be safely cast.

A slightly cleaner solution would be to pass `np.byte` as one of the arguments to `np.result_type`:

```
newtype = np.result_type(x, y, np.byte)
```

This also takes care of cases where `x` and `y` have potentially different dtypes.

Comment: Nice solution. There is one intrinsically tricky case: uint64 has to be either promoted to int64 or a float type, and both have limitations. promote_types will offer a float type. A bit of extra code can give int64 if that's what is preferred.